# Javascript XML parsing or alternative

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing

I'm building a Javascript preview function for a blog back-end (much like the one used on this website), and I'd like to be able to parse some custom tags that normally get parsed by PHP. I am wondering if it's possible to use the JS XML parser to parse content from a textarea that would look like:

```
<img=1>

Use for
<url=http://apwit.com>testing</url>
purposes only!
```

I read on another question here once that using regex to parse things like this is a bad idea because of the many many exceptions there could be. What do you think?

Comment: That's not well-formed xml. No xml parser would parse that. A regex is the best you'll do in the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this: http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_parsertest2

It parses xml from a string and uses the fast native XML parsing engine from the browser.

Explanation and discussion:

http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_parser.asp