# Javascript split string between multiple spans

Tags: javascript, split, match

I have scoured Google looking for an answer but I cant seem to find one.

I need to split the following string into separate variables

the string is stored as a variable 
:-

```
var location = autocomplete.getPlace();
var address = location['formatted_address'];

Output:-

<span class="street-address">Street address</span>, <span class="locality">Town</span>, <span class="region">County</span> <span class="postal-code">Post Code</span>, <span class="country-name">Country</span>
```

eg.

```
var street = "Street address";
var town = "Town";
var county = "County";
var postc = "Post Code";
var country = "Country";
```

So I need to get the contents between

```
 <span class="street-address"></span>
 <span class="locality"></span>
 etc...
```

Sometime there are extra spans sometimes less.

I have looked at some javascript but it only gets the content between:-

```
 <span class="locality"> and the very last </span>
```

Any help in the right direction would be greatly

Comment: Could you post your javascript code here? Then it might be easier to help you improve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript XML parsing or alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787982/javascript-xml-parsing-or-alternative)

Comment: @Nicole     var location = autocomplete.getPlace(); var address = location['formatted_address'];

Answer (score 1):

Are you using plain javascript? or jQuery?

in javascript you can get the text inside an element via:

```
var1 = document.getElementByClass("street-address").innerText
```

or in jQuery:

```
var streetAddress = $('.street-address').text();
var city= $('.city').text();
```

Comment: I'm using javascript but the address is stored as a var

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery:

```
var 1 = $('span.street-address').text();
var 2 = $('span.locality').text();
var 3 = $('span.region').text();
var 4 = $('span.postal-code').text();
var 5 = $('span.country-name').text();
```

It should be that simple, unless I am missing something in the question.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention the address is a variable:-

Comment: var location = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var address = location['formatted_address'];

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jQuery? Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/zsxar4r4/

```
var address = [];
$('span').each(function(idx, span) {
    address.push($(span).html());
})
console.log(address);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getElementsByClassName()` method, which will return an array-like object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

```
var addressData = document.getElementsByClassName('address');

//And than do something with the object. You can access it like an array:

console.log(addressData[2].innerHTML);
```